# Sorting Deep Nested lists in Python by third nested list

Tags: python, sorting

If this is a duplicate, then I'd be glad to delete the question.

In python, I have a list that has the following structure, with none of the names necessarily being the same:

```
[[xy, ["Name 3", ["SubName 1", "SubName 2"]], 
      ["Name 1", ["NameSub 1", "NameSub 2"]], ...],
 [yz, ["Name 10", ["SubNamex 1", "SubNamex 2"]], 
      ["Name 6", ["NameSubx 1", "NameSubx 2"]], ...]]
```

I want to sort first by the first index, "xy" and "yz", and then sort the items with each nested list by "Name x". So my sorted list should look like this:

```
[[xy, ["Name 1", ["NameSub 1", "NameSub 2"]],
      ["Name 3", ["SubName 1", "SubName 2"]], ...],
 [yz, ["Name 6", ["NameSubx 1", "NameSubx 2"]], 
      ["Name 10", ["SubNamex 1", "SubNamex 2"]], ...]]
```

I have tried:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

and

```
mylist.sort(key=itemgetter(2,1))
```

and different variations of the indices, with no success.

Comment: What is your expectation ?or expected result

Comment: FYI, If a question is a duplicate then it is still useful on SO as it directs new users to good answers, so don't be too hasty to delete :) See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate) meta post

Comment: Hi @HariomSingh, my expected result is the second list I posted. You'll see that the list is sorted by the "xy" and "yz", and then by "Name 1" and "Name 3" within that initial nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, iterate the array sorting the inner nested elements and finally sort the outer elements.
The code is provided below:

```
srtli=[]
for ele in li:
    tmp=ele[1:]
    tmp.sort()
    for ele_tmp in tmp:
        ele_tmp[1].sort()
    srtli.append([ele[0]]+tmp)
srtli.sort()
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I was hoping that there was a way of using one of the "known" functions, but this approach makes sense and is intuitive enough. The second "for" isn't needed though. Thank you @vineeth560

Answer (score 0):

**try with this :-**

```
a =     [['xy', ["Name 3", ["SubName 1", "SubName 2"]],
            ["Name 1", ["NameSub 1", "NameSub 2"]]],
        ['yz', ["Name 10", ["SubNamex 1", "SubNamex 2"]], 
                ["Name 6", ["NameSubx 1", "NameSubx 2"]]]]
# a.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
for i in a:
    i.sort(key = lambda x : x[1])
    print i[-1],',',i[:-1] #or you can do print i only
```